# Can I make some variables template specific?

Tags: c++, templates

For instance, here is my thread barrier/section type thing

```
template <bool switchable = false, bool counting = false>
struct SimpleBarrier {
private:
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<bool> enabled;
    std::atomic<int> inside;

public:
    SimpleBarrier() {
        if (switchable) enabled.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        if (counting) inside.store(0, std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void enter() {
        if (switchable && !enabled.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) return;
        if (counting) inside.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock);
    }

    void leave() {
        if (counting) inside.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel);
    }

    void release() {
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void enable() {
        if (switchable) {
            enabled.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }

    void disable() {
        if (switchable) {
            enabled.store(false, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }

    bool is_empty() {
        if (counting) return inside.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0;
        return false;
    }
};
```

Initially I was just going to make a bunch of classes like "SwitchableBarrier" and "CountingSection" etc but then I started needing combinations like "SwitchableCountingSection" and there are probably going to be more qualities so to avoid making a dozen classes, I rolled them into one class using template parameters to turn certain qualities on/off.

Using template parameters as conditionals allows the compiler to optimize away unused qualities so there's no extra overhead from unused ones. The question is though - is it possible to also make it optimize away class variables?

Take the variable "inside" for instance, if counting == false then it is completely useless and doesn't need to be there. Can I have template parameter specific class variables?

Comment: Define a template specialization for `counting == false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any member, even when unused, has a different address. Also, the compiler won't remove it. However, there is a simple trick: empty bases don't need to get their own address. If that is combined with specialization, you can get rid of any data. For example:

```
template <bool, typename T>
class conditional_count {
    std::atomic<T> value;
public:
    T    load_count() { return value.load(std::memory_order_aquire); }
    void store_count(T v) { value.store(v, std::memory_order_release); }
    // ...
};
template <typename T>
struct conditional_count<false, T> {
    int  load_count() { return 0; }
    void store_count(T) {}
    // ...
};

template <bool switchable = false, bool counting = false>
struct SimpleBarrier
     : private conditional_count<counting> {
    // use this->load_count(), this->store_count(), etc.
 };
```

It would be possible to create a more general `conditional_atomic<...>` but it would require taking an extra tag type to identify which one is being used and it becomes a bit more annoying to use. However, the overall approach is to put the logic into a base with suitable functions to access the variable and provide a specialization just doing nothing.